# Get integer from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, parsing, sdk, uiwebview, integer

I have a webpage that outputs an integer that I need to parse. I know how to get a string from a website in an UIWebView, but I need to get it as an integer. Converting a string to an integer using [myString integerValue] won't work here. How can I do this?

Edit: Here is my error
[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What error does it give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the warning is that your variable is not an integer, but a pointer to an integer.

```
NSInteger *test = [onlineUsers integerValue];
          ^
 Get rid of the asterisk
```